# Someone provide a tutorial link for Pandoc txt to tex

Tags: unicode, pandoc

can someone provide a link to either documentation or a tutorial on how to convert txt files to tex files.  You will probably have to extrapolate this question since I don't know enough to compose a more precise question.  I want to convert some txt files to basic tex files.  They are utf8, and I don't want to print them with notepad or a text editor, but rather have LaTeX typeset them.

I'm visualizing that I will need to create a LaTeX template for Pandoc. I have a little experience with LaTeX and know how to create basic documents using the basic classes and the basic commands, but would be lost if I had to create my own package or class.  I don't know anything about pandoc except that it's a command line conversion tool that can roughly convert from one filetype to another, with a probably loss of formatting due to differences in features of the filetypes.  My txt files have zero formatting syntax coded inside them, it's just unicode characters in utf8 txt files.  All of the characters are American Latin types.

Someone please provide a helpful tutorial to pandoc, or documentation, or correct my ignorance as much as possible.

Comment: IMHO, questions about pandoc itself are not on-topic, but about produce LaTeX (with or without pandoc) are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the requirements of the OP, the simplest way is to create the following template (and name it `templates.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

$body$

\end{document}
```

Then Pandoc can be called with the following command

```
pandoc --template=templatex.tex <file.txt> -o <file.tex>
```

where `<file.txt>` is the name of the input `txt` file and `<file.tex>` is  the name of the output to be created by pandoc.

By the way Pandoc documentation for templates is available at http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-for-wrapper-scripts.

Comment: +1. More intrepid pandoctors might want to modify [`default.latex`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex) to suit their needs, or to get inspired about the possibilities available.

Answer (score 3):

> Pandoc txt to tex

*Sensu stricto* it is not as easy as it looks.

`Pandoc` only write to plain text but **does not read plain text**, thus is not exactly the right tool, except if you want that plain text will be **interpreted as Markdown**  (that however, very probably is what you really want).

> My txt files have zero formatting syntax coded inside them

Probably is not true (for the point of view of `pandoc`). Probably the text in the converted file will be plagued of LaTeX commands no matter how simple your template will be, except if the text has not other structure that normal paragraphs. But a text with simple headers, or some list, for example:

```
Heading 
-------

Vivamus 12% nunc & nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, 
velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Nam rutrum augue a leo. 

- First item text
- Second item text
    1. First subitem text
    2. Second subitem text
```

...look like plain text, but really have some Markdown syntax that will be converted to LaTeX, so the result with the template of Guido's answer will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Heading}\label{heading}

Vivamus 12\% nunc \& nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, 
velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Nam rutrum augue a leo.  

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item 
  First itemtext
\item
  Second itemtext

  \begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \tightlist
  \item
    First itemtext
  \item
    Second itemtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Today  you can omit `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (is now the deafult) but the result is nice (the PDF look perfect) ...or a major drawback if you want strictly what you asked. Suppose that you do not want sections and list LaTeX syntax, only start editing a LaTeX text without structure. Then you need only escaping special characters ( `$ & % # _ { } ~ ^ \`) since this produce lost of some text (any text after `%` will be treated as a comment) or fatal rendering errors, but there are not a pandoc option for this, afaik.

> I will need to create a LaTeX template for Pandoc.

In general, no. You do not have to worry about templates. By default is applied a template that work in most cases. So this work also:

```
pandoc -s <file.txt> -o <file.tex>
```

However, it could be a good idea have your own template if the default template disturb you in some way (for example, you want a cleaner preamble to star editing the LaTeX file). Also it will be better rename `file.txt` to `file.md`(so it can be recognized correctly as markdown text by text editors and you).

But you can also work in plain text (markdown) *without pandoc conversions* and still produce nice LaTeX PDF prints, just working only with one LaTeX document with this structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
Your plain text here
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

It must be compiled with `lualatex`. You can also use `pdflatex`,  but it should be able of access the shell in order to run some Lua code (run texdoc markdown` for more info).

Or if you want to maintain/edit the original `<file.txt>` anyway, you can also:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\markdownInput{<file.txt>}
\end{document}
```

Finally, in case that you do not want any Markdown format (just produce a PDF as seen in the plain text editor) the thing are a little more complex. Probably the best could be sanitizing some Markdown syntax and then import to LyX:

```
pandoc <file.md> -t plain -o <file.txt> && lyx --import text <file.txt>
```

And then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to obtain the PDF. If you want to join the lines, AFAIK there are no command line options in LyX, but it is possible via LyX menu <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Import</kbd> > <kbd>Plaint Text, Join Lines ...</kbd> or without LyX, covert directly to LaTeX with the perl script [txt2latex](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/support/txt2latex/txt2latex):

```
pandoc <file.md> -t plain | txt2latex > <file.tex>
```

In this case the result is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Heading

Vivamus 12\% nunc \& nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut
porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Nam rutrum augue a leo.

-   First item text
-   Second item text
    1.  First subitem text
    2.  Second subitem text

\end{document}
```

The good is that if you do not want to join lines at some moment, is enough add `\obeylines` after `\begin{document}`

Or, in case that you want just show the text verbatim:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
 <Paste here your plain text>
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Or just include the original file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{borra.md}
\end{document}
```

Or simply, change `\markdownInput` by `\markdownRendererInputVerbatim` in the example using the `markdown` package.

Comment: that's right.  my txt files truly are plain txt files with zero formatting markup.  I've since noticed that when I try to convert a latex file back into a "textile"[sic] using Try Pandoc sample page on the internet, that it actually places some sort of markup into the txt files, like "_" before/after an emphaised word or "*" before/after some bold words.  I'm studying how to create my own plain text format.  Also, a major annoyance is that insertion of  7 bit quotation ``quotation marks' ' into my supposedly unicode tex files

Comment: @user12711 Do not use `- t textile` ("to textile" option of `pandoc`) , but `-t plain`  to export to plain text. "Textile" is a markup language. Problably you may want use the program  `detex`   to strip TeX commands from a `.tex` file.

Comment: detex is exactly what I'm looking for to go back and forth between latex and txt.  I'm going to be using my pandcoc myText.tex exports within an import statement in a latex master document.  I also need the ability to export them back out into a txt file (in case I make corrections within the myText.tex files that I import).  The only other thing I want to learn how to get pandoc to do is use export unicode quotation marks rather than the ` ` something quoted ' ' ascii characters